# What do I take as the random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> There are 500 misprints in a book of 500 pages. What is the probability
>   that a given page will contain at most 3 misprints?

How do I solve this? What do I take as the random variable here?

Comment: I would use a [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).  The variable is the number of misprints on the page, with a mean of $1$.  I get about $.981$ as the probability.

Comment: The Poisson distribution is a good approximation here, I agree. There is a more direct combinatorial answer, but it is a lot more complicated and probably very close to the Poisson answer.

Comment: Why Poisson rather than Binomial?

Comment: @Under Because $B(1,p)$ is close to $Pois(p)$ for $p\ll 1$ and hence we can approximate $B(n,p)$ by $Pois(np)$ for $p\ll 1$ not too far away from the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force approach:

Model the process as balls in urns.  That is, we have $500$ "balls" (=misprints) which we must place in $500$ "urns" (=pages).  Suppose that the placement is wholly independent (which urn one ball goes into has no bearing on any other balls).

Then...the probability that a given misprint occurs on a given page is $p=\frac 1{500}$ and the probability that a given page holds exactly $k$ misprints is $$Prob(k)=\binom {500}kp^k(1-p)^{500-k}$$

Using this model, we compute $$Prob(≤3)\sim .98113451$$

The Poisson model gives $\sim .98101184$ so the two methods give extremely similar results.

To me, the Poisson model is more reflective of what is intended.  That is, I imagine that the probability of misprints is proportional to the number of pages under consideration.  The binomial model ensures that exactly $500$ misprints appear throughout the book which might feel more reflective of the given data...but is it?  When someone says "these $500$ pages contain $500$ misprints" I don't imagine that either count is exact...rather that they are just saying "there's a mean of one misprint per page".  But of course it is a matter of interpretation.  To be sure, the Poisson model is extremely easy to compute with and, as the two models are very close, computational ease is a strong advantage.

To stress: As discussed in the comments below, the ball/urn model is also an approximation (however shoddy the publisher, you really can't have $500$ misprints on one page). In situations like these, it tends to come down to two things:  A. Which model better fits the physical situation (often more an art than a science) and B. computational ease.

Comment: Well, Poisson is also only an approximation to the process you describe because there is only so many misprints you can have per page. In that sense, the number of mistakes on each page is Binomial and hence the number of total error is also binomial - not Poisson - with the same mean - but larger $n$ // When somebody tells you: The coin was flipped 100 times - do you imagine exactly 100 flips or 50 head/tail "runs"?

Comment: Per above, if you consider all positions (not pages) where errors might happen, even the binomial approach you (and others) used is only an approximation to the "true" distribution.

Comment: @A.S.  Fair enough...though the cap on "misprints per page" also restricts the ball/urn model unless you want to assign a probability of error to each character on the page...which then loses the "exactly $500$".  Absolutely agreed that even the binomial is an approximation.  To me, Poisson is obviously the way to go...but I thought it worth sketching an alternative.

Comment: Could you clarify how does considering each character/misprint as a separate unit loses "exactly 500"? // I agree that Poisson, for reasons of simplicity and ease of computation, is the way to go both as the approximation for the misprint generating process (which, when conditioned on M=500, yields binomial number of errors per page) and as approximation of this very conditioned Poisson (binomial) by unconditioned one. I just thought it's worth noting that the "true" cond distribution of errors per page is hypergeometric with binomial dispersing it out and Poisson squashing it down afterwards.

Comment: @A.S.  Oh, I just meant that one could read the problem as implying a probability that a given character was misprinted.  As a caricature, if there were only three characters per page then the answer to the given problem is $1$ regardless of the model.  But, I think we agree that Poisson really captures the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume the number of misprints be the
poisson distributed random variable $X$
with $\lambda = 1$.

The probability you are looking for is

$$P(X \leq 3)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)= $$

$$=\frac{e^{-1}1^0}{0!}
+\frac{e^{-1}1^1}{1!}
+\frac{e^{-1}1^2}{2!}
+\frac{e^{-1}1^3}{3!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Every misprint has a probability of $1/500$ of appearing on the chosen page, and a probability of $499/500$ of appearing elsewhere. The probability $p(k)$ that $k$ misprints appear on that page is then governed by a binomial distribution:
$$
p(k)={500\choose k}\left({1\over500}\right)^k\left({499\over500}\right)^{500-k}.
$$
You then need to compute $p(0)+p(1)+p(2)+p(3)$.

This case is also well approximated by a Poisson distribution, if that better fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> A [random variable](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Random_variable) is a function that assigns a real number to each point in a sample space $S$. It is a numerical-valued variable that represents outcomes in an experiment or random process.

In this case, possible outcomes are the number of misprints on a page, and the sample space is $\{0,1,2, ... ,500\}$ whereby an outcome of $0$ means that there are no misprints on a page, and $500$ means there are $500$ misprints on a page.

In general, whenever you want to define a random variable, consider the sample space of your experiment and define the random variable such that it assigns a value to each point in the sample space.

Having this sample space of $\{0,1,2, ... ,500\}$, we can define a discrete random variable $X$ as
$$X=number\space of \space misprints \space on \space a \space page$$

Hence, $P(X=x)$ means the probability that there are $x$ number of misprints in a page. Since question is asking for at most 3 misprints, we are looking for $P(X\leq x)$.

To solve this, you can let $X$~$Binomial\big(500,\frac{1}{500}\big)$, whereby $500$ is the number of independent pages, and $\frac{1}{500}$ is the probability of having a misprint.

Thus, 
$$P(X=x)={500\choose x}\bigg(\frac{1}{500}\bigg)^x\bigg(\frac{499}{500}\bigg)^{500-x} $$

Furthermore, since $X$ is a discrete $r.v.$, 
$$P(X\leq 3)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)$$

You can approximate this using Poisson, as already discussed on this page, or calculate the sum of probabilities as shown above.